# How can we uncheck a radio button

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know how can we uncheck a radio button. It should work like a checkbox.

Comment: Click on the next radio button.

Comment: To check/uncheck use checkbox. Radiobuttons purpose is different.

Comment: If it should work as a checkbox then use a checkbox

Comment: Man, this question got destroyed.  It's actually a good question.

Comment: @ButI'mNotAWrapperClass: Yes, you are 100% correct.  Sometimes you want a collection of buttons that have a group, like a RadioButton (so there is only ever one checked) BUT can have no item checked.  People saying, "Use a CheckBox" are not seeing the bigger picture.  It shouldn't be that difficult (or wrong) for a RadioButton to have an option to deselect.

Answer (score 18):

Use the following code to use radio button like check box.

```
    bool isChecked =false;
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isChecked = radioButton1.Checked;
    }

    private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked && !isChecked)
            radioButton1.Checked = false;
        else
        {
            radioButton1.Checked = true;
            isChecked = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many Thanks.. I got it working with this code.

Comment: This caused me a stack overflow. Try this code instead (I would pose it as an answer but the q is closed):

        bool isChecked = false;
        private void radioButon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isChecked && radioButon1.Checked)
                radioButon1.Checked = false;
            isChecked = radioButon1.Checked;
        }

Answer (score 6):

Radio buttons are used when you want the user to choose, usually, one or more items from a series of options, so by the end, you will have at least one selected item. If you want to provide the user to uncheck, then, you should really be using a Checkbox in the first place.

At most in your case, you could provide some functionality such as a button to *reset* the radio buttons, by doing something like `rdBtn.Checked = false;`

Answer (score 3):

This might work:

```
private void radio_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (radio.Checked)
  {
    radio.Checked = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried this, but the radio button never get checked with it. However, I got the resolution of the problem I was facing..Thank you once again.

Comment: Well question was about unchecking :) Someone else already posted answer that will work for checking too